# xaml parse exception while accessing class from another page in windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I created a class with some public members. Now I want to access those members from MainPage.xaml.cs page.

So I created an object for that class and accessed its members. When I run that app Xaml parse exception occurs.

I debugged it and found the exception to be at InitializeComponents() method in the main constructor.

How to solve this issue or how can I access a class members in any page in windows phone apps.

sample code

```
public class Mainpage
{
    Mainpage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    void Calculate()
    {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        int ans = calc.add(5,6);
        textBlock1.text = ans.ToString();
    }
}

// This is in another separate class in the solution
public class Calculate
{
    public add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error you have means that you have something wrong with your XAML file (this is probably not connected with your .cs file). Check your XAML code for some mistakes and so on (try to comment/uncomment some blocks of code - find what caused the error).

Comment: Check the innermost exception.